# How does makeindex sort alphabets of a language?

Tags: indexing

How does makeindex sort alphabets of a language? How many languages does it support? Is the sorting hardcoded or does it provide someways to create sorting alphabets for a new language?

Comment: I'm afraid that MakeIndex supports only the Latin alphabet without diacritics. Turn to Xindy for multilanguage support.

Comment: Interestingly, it sorts Arabic alphabets too.

Comment: This might be a byproduct of the encoding. MakeIndex doesn't really understand Unicode, so bizarre things can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MakeIndex predates Unicode and hasn't been updated for many years. It supports only the Latin alphabet without diacritics; unique exception are German umlauts that can be input with Babel shorthands `"a`, `"o` and `"u` (but this requires a particular option and a suitable `.ist` file).

If MakeIndex appears to work with different alphabets or Unicode code blocks, perhaps, it's just a lucky coincidence, because it *doesn't* understand Unicode.

What might happen is that it sees UTF-8 pairs, so it sorts with respect to them: "ALEF" before "BEH" because the former is `<D8><A7>` and the latter is `<D8><A8>`; and so on. However it would also sort "YEH WITH HAMZA ABOVE" before "ALEF" and I don't know if this is correct.